# Show div if validation fails

Tags: validation, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I want this div to show if the form validation is unsuccessful.

```
<div class="alert">
  <strong>Warning!</strong> @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Fix these errors:")
</div>
```

I tried to wrapped it inside

```
if(! ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
```

but div is not displayed when submitting the form. Probably because there is not post back due jquery validation. The validation logic seems alright, if i remove the if-statement validation summary list all incorrect input fields.

How can I toggle the visibility of the div based on the validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply this simple script.  It's not very sophisticated, but it should do the trick

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.alert').hide(); //hides the div on page load
    $('#submit').click(function () {  //assumes your submit button has id="submit"
        $('.alert').show(); //shows the div when submit is clicked
    });
});
```

As you can see, this doesn't actually care about the validation.  It simply makes the 'alert' div visible when the submit button is clicked.  If there are validation errors, the div will show with your warnings.  If the form is valid, I'm assuming a refresh, or redirect, so the div will never actually have a chance to show.

Comment: Your workaround has the correct user experience therefor I upvoted it. However, it feels like I missing something. Who wants to output the error message `(Fix these errors)` before the form is even completed. Feels like `@Html.ValidationSummary` should have some toggle visibility mechanism to it...

Comment: True.  However, if you simply don't wrap @Html.ValidationSummary in a div it will hide itself until needed...

Comment: Are your sure? When I started out the validation I left the `@Html.ValidationSummary` by it self with no div and the text `Fix these errors` is there right from the start.

Comment: Yes I'm sure.  If it happens again set the bool param to true and see what field is throwing.

Comment: Absolutely right, I thought I tried that. Then it is easier to accept limitations with wrapped html elements. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

I rewrote the accepted answer. If the server connection is slow the error div will be visible during the server request. Even if there is no errors. I changed it to check if the form is valid when submitting the form. This code snippet assumes you have one form.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".alert").hide(); //hides the div on page load

    $("form").submit(function () {
        if (!$(this).valid()) {
            $('.alert').show();
        }
    });        
});
```